# WCF and Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm totaly newbie with WCF and Xamarin. I need to retrieve simple data from WCF.

this is my **ViewModel:**

```
 #region Constructor
    public ItemViewModel()
        : base()
    {
       DataStore = DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<Item>>() ?? new ItemDataStore();
        Title = "Items";
    }
    #endregion
```

**ItemDataStore**

```
public class ItemDataStore: IDataStore<Item>
    {
        List<Item> items;

        public ItemDataStore()
        {

            items = new List<Item>();
            ServiceWCF serviceWCF = new ServiceWCF();

            ItemWCF[] test = serviceWCF.GetItems(); //here I'm gettin error

            foreach (var item in test)
            {
                Item i = new Item();
                i.Name= item.Name;
                i.Price= item.Price;
                items.Add(i);
            }
        }
}
```

**error msg**
[image]

**WCF**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServicePawelWCF
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<ItemWCF> GetItems();
}

[DataContract]
public class PrzedmiotWCF
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
 public List<ItemWCF> GetItems()
{

        dataEntities db = new dataEntities();
        return db.Item.Select(x => new ItemWCF
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Price = x.Price,
        }).ToList();
}
```

for WCF I opened the secend Visual Studio wrote above code and just run with all default settings. at Microsoft Client Test WCF application the WCF is working and retrieve correct data by array.

at App Xamarin I added references to android project.

Please be forgiving is my first contact with WCF

**EDIT**:
"Can you post the full exception, with inner exceptions and stacktrace?"
[image][image]

**EDIT2**
I'm using xamarin android emulator, and i think this emulator dosent see my localhost iis

here i found the solution:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/walkthrough-working-with-wcf](http://tutorial)
but after run administrator command propt the:
`netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.143:9608/ user=everyone` (*header*: Configuring Remote Access to IIS Express) command dosent work. i'm getting error: `Creating SDDL failed, Error: 1332`

Comment: Can you post the full exception, with inner exceptions and stacktrace?

Comment: I dont have 'inner exceptions' just 'open exception settings'

Comment: ... Oh, by the way... I noticed you call the `ServiceWCF` in the constructor of `ItemDataStore`; in my experience this gives "hard to debug errors" when something is raising an exception. If you can, try to put it in a method. It will not fix your issue, but possibly make it easier to detect.

Comment: You don't really need WCF these days. Please consider ASP.NET Web API or ASP.NET Core.